# Line Chart in powerpoint using Open XML SDK 2.5

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, linechart

I want to add a new slide to an existing powerpoint file and add a new line chart.

The number of series and data points and labels will be dynamic. How to achieve it using Open XML SDK? I couldn't find any good documentation on charts.

Thanks